# Accessing AngularJs Controller properties from the root node ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to access the angular controller property from the same tag where `ng-controller` is defined and hide the tag using `ng-if` if the property `languages` is having less than one element.

To be precise this is what my **not working code** looks like:

```
<li ng-controller="LanguageController" ng-if="languages.length > 1">
    ...
</li>
```

But if I do something like this then **it works**.

```
<li ng-controller="LanguageController">
    <div ng-if="languages.length > 1">...</div>
</li>
```

When I try this

```
<li ng-controller="LanguageController" data-val="{{languages.length}}">
...
```

The output is `... data-val="1"..` which means

> I can access the properties in the root element itself

To add to it, it also works when I use `ng-show` to hide my root element. Thanks to @sarjan-desai.

---

**Question :** But still why doesn't the `ng-if` work and remove my root `li` object, while the ng-show works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `ng-if` or other `ng` directive in same element where you define your controller.

**ng-if**

> The [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

**ng-show**

> The [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on
>   the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The element is shown
>   or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the
>   element.

`ng-if` **removes or recreates** elements which means when setting `li` element property, condition become false and ng-if remove `controller` and whole element.

For `ng-show` it's only **shows or hides** elements not adding or removing so in starting if condition `false` it only hide element not remove it and when `$scope` bind to element, it shows the data because condition becomes true.

Check below snippet

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.addresses = [{
    'state': 'AL'
  }, {
    'state': 'CA'
  }, {
    'state': 'FL'
  }];
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl1', function($scope) {

  $scope.addresses = [];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<li ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-show="addresses.length > 0">Billing State: <tt>State selected: {{addresses}}</tt>
</li>
  <li ng-controller="MyCtrl1" ng-show="addresses.length > 0">This will not show.<tt>State selected: {{addresses}}</tt>
</li>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. it's possible. now only i realized the problem is that `ng-if` doesn't remove the item when its in the root element. I wil update the question :)

Answer (score 1):

As a short answer : no.

Because when you are on your root element, your controller is not here yet. So the current scope is the scope of the parent controller (or the root scope if this is your first controller).

Comment: Thank you so how can i remove the root tag? Do i need to use the parent controller to do this?

Comment: You can only do that if `languages` is a property of the parent controller.